# Powerbuilder - Enabled vs DisplayOnly

Tags: powerbuilder

If we define a textbox type and set property Enabled to false.

```
global type parent_type from editmask
...
boolean Enabled=false
...
end type
```

At this point, the textbox parent_type is not editable.
Now if we define a child-textbox type to inherit the above textbox type with property DisplayOnly set to false

```
type child_type from parent_type within some_window
...
boolean DisplayOnly=false
...
end type
```

Is this child-type editable? I am new to Powerbuilder and really have no idea if DisplayOnly property can override Enabled property to make the textbox editable.

(the Powerbuilder version of my source code is 4.0. I am working for a project that requires us to convert a system written in Powerbuilder many years ago into a web application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you gave, the descendant will be disabled. The `DisplayOnly` property only matters when the control is enabled.

**Enabled** - Whether you can move focus to the control and interact with it.

**DisplayOnly** - Whether you can change the contents of the control. The control must be enabled for this property to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Enabled is a property of visual object ancestor. It activates and deactivates the object as a whole.

DisplayOnly is a TextBox property that disables edition while mantaining the rest of the object attributes. You can focus on the control and, most useful, you can scroll through the text in the control,which you cannot do in a disabled(enabled=false) control.